# REST api call using method getbyemail for user in a group returns error "Cannot find resource for the request getbytitle"

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Users exist in sharepoint group:
[image]

If I do simple GET request in browser:
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite2/_api/web/sitegroups/getbytitle('TestGroup')/users/getbyemail('john.theuser@mycompany.com')

Returns error: *"Cannot find resource for the request getbytitle."*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getbyName to get specific site group:

/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyName('GroupName')/users/getbyemail('john.theuser@mycompany.com')